# Remove android:icon and label

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

How can I remove or hide the android:icon and android:label from ActionBar? I know is possible remove all ActionBar, but just need the both parameters like my image.

Manifest.xml

```
  <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".Login"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="br.com.fourop.meuponto.Main"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
    </application>
```

Thanks for help!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove the icon and title by calling setDisplayShowHomeEnabled and setDisplayShowTitleEnabled from getActionBar() method

so simply this way

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

        //the rest of your code...
}
```

Comment: Nadir B Thanks a lot! It's works! But I've one more question if possible.. I've a space where I was the object, is possible fit it ?

Comment: I don't understand your second question which object ?